# An old car in bad condition

Tags: single-word-requests

I am in need of a word to describe an old, bad conditioned car that is yet still running.

- ***Ragged*** came to my mind, but it seems to be inappropriate for things not related to clothing.
- ***Wrecked*** is also not what I'd like to use.

However, this shall be used in a work of literature, so a neat paraphrase would be fine.

Comment: A-AEnglish: *raggledy* (ragged)

Comment: ["clunker"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clunker) comes to my mind.

Comment: "Junker" is another term.

Comment: @LittleEva I have never heard the term "raggledy" (AmE, not sure what A-AEnglish is though). I HAVE frequently heard "raggedy" (and it's intensive form "raggedy-ass")

Comment: Surprised "jalopy" hasn't made any answers here

Comment: It's the second answer in the list at the time of writing @y3sh.

Comment: Your examples are adjectives; lots of answers have suggested nouns. Could you clarify if nouns are also acceptable, or do you require an adjective? Additionally, is slang appropriate for your intended use, or should slang be avoided?

Comment: I'd just call it a bucket of bolts.

Comment: @Harrison Paine -  African-American English *informal* "raggledy", "raggledy-*assed*"

Comment: If you need adjectives, try "Junky", "Trashy"

Comment: If you can use more of a phrase, I might recommend "looks like it's held together with bailing wire and duct tape, and running on prayers and borrowed time" :)

Comment: If you can stand some sarcasm, the word I learned for these growing up was "a beauty". :-)

Comment: @DoktorJ I couldn't use this with good conscience for it would feel like stealing, but I highly appreciate your suggestion for its greatness! :)

Comment: @Sprottenwels hah, thanks! I really just mashed together a bunch of idioms -- "held together with bailing wire" and "held together with duct tape" (ngrams: https://goo.gl/jmOjLK), "running on borrowed time" (ngram: https://goo.gl/bbvICd), and "on a [wing and a] prayer" (ngram: https://goo.gl/RddUuX). Feel free to use them in any combination you wish, or use them as the basis for your own idiom-combo!

Comment: Quite simply, **junker** is factually the usual term in most of the USA (if you were looking for an AmE answer).  This QA is a sad example of how this site sometimes works: people have put a lot of effort in to thinking up! exciting! terms for the issue at hand. Anyone who has ever eg. been in the USA would just point out that "junker" is the usual term used (in most regions, and amongst English-speakers) (ie, not Spanish, Korean, etc speakers, who have their own slang).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Somewhat old fashioned, and not an adjective like your examples, but a noun, **[jalopy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jalopy)**:

> - (Informal) An old, dilapidated motor vehicle, especially an automobile. (AHD)

---

Comments below suggest adding the following:

**Usage example**: "We hopped in the jalopy and rattled off to town."

**Competitors**: Words like *junker, heap,* and *clunker* are probably also heard more frequently in the New York than in the south.  *Jalopy* has the advantage of unambiguously denoting an automobile without additional context, which is unlikely to be true of the other words.

**Regional note**: While it is true that *jalopy* originated in the USA, it appears to have been adopted in the UK as well, perhaps owing to the American military presence coinciding with the word's peak in popularity.  Also note that *jalopy* has not been surpassed by *junker* or *clunker* in either British or American English, according to ngrams, though it must be noted that this does not reflect the spoken language:

[English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jalopy%2Cclunker%2Cjunker&year_start=1890&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjalopy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclunker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjunker%3B%2Cc0)

[American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jalopy%2Cclunker%2Cjunker&year_start=1890&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjalopy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclunker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjunker%3B%2Cc0)

[British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jalopy%2Cclunker%2Cjunker&year_start=1890&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjalopy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclunker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjunker%3B%2Cc0)

**Archaic**: If we take *archaic* to mean *having the characteristics of the language of the past and surviving chiefly in specialized uses* (m-w.com) then yes, "jalopy" is archaic, as "somewhat old-fashioned" was intended to indicate.  However, a list of archaic words found at http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/archaic-words-american consists mostly of words that are far less familiar than "jalopy."  It appears to be a question of where we draw the line.

It is also possible that jalopy is enjoying a revival, as evidenced by the popular culture references mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I haven't heard "jalopy" in probably 40 years (it was a term my grandmother's generation used).  I would regard it as archaic in modern vernacular.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decrepit_car

Comment: @HotLicks - you obviously never listened to "Car Talk" on NPR...

Comment: @HotLicks Chris Cagle's song "Wal-Mart Parking Lot" uses _jalopy_, and it was released in 2005.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't know for sure, but I assume that this is how the popular auto blog [Jalopnik](http://jalopnik.com/) derives its name.

Comment: @phoog - I notice you're in NY. Down in the Southern states, we usually hear the term "junker", "heap" or "clunker". You may want to add those for a more complete answer. You may also want to specify that this is American English and not British. The term "jalopy" seems to have originated in 1920's America.

Comment: @Floris - Considering that one of the Magliozzi brothers is the same age I am and the other is dead, I consider that proof of my statement.

Comment: @HotLicks fwiw, Google Ngrams shows "jalopy" to be more popular than both "junker" and "clunker", and has shown pretty steady usage (no significant decline) since the 1960s. There was a big decline for 'jalopy' from the 1940s to the mid-1960s, but since then it has stayed in fairly constant usage. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jalopy%2Cjunker%2Cclunker&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjalopy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjunker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclunker%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @nohat - Note that Ngram reflects uses in published sources that have been scanned by Google, most of which do not reflect current argot but rather the language of 30-50 years past.  And often the uses are contrived in some way.  If you look at the found references you will have difficulty finding any that reflect current usage.

Comment: @HotLicks the word might have a bit of an old-fashioned flavor, but the fact is it remains in current use—it's not "archaic" and it's certainly not the case that no one is using it. Here it is being used in a video game review:  https://goo.gl/9ns2xk Here it is being combined with the contemporary slang "for the win": https://goo.gl/1HNq5x It's pretty trivial to find examples of unmarked contemporary use of "jalopy". The authors don't mark the word specially with quotes or try to define it in context—it is assumed that readers will be familiar with the word.

Comment: @HotLicks I am inclined to agree that it is archaic, depending on the threshold required for that designation.  I've added a brief discussion to the answer.

Comment: @Omegacron the term originated in America, but seems to be roughly as well known in Britain as in the US.  I suppose that's because its popularity peaked in the 40s, when there were lots of Americans in Britain.  I don't suppose there's much difference in the use of "jalopy" or the other words you mention in the south or in NY.  I'd be surprised to hear someone refer to a car as a jalopy in casual speech in either place, and unsurprised to hear one of the other words.

Comment: @nohat - If you actually check that second reference you'll see that it reenforces my point -- the time period being described is apparently the 50s or 60s.

Comment: @phoog it definitely seems that "jalopy" experienced a heyday in the 1940s and 1950s, but the ngram shows pretty steady usage since usage flattened out in the mid-1960s—no evidence of a recent revival, but rather just a slang term that became established in the language for occasional use. Contrast with "swanky" and "groovy" two slang terms from the 1940s and 1970s, respectively, which *are* both experiencing a revival. https://goo.gl/9KELUt

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not sure what your point is, exactly? No one is disputing that the heyday of "jalopy"was the 1940s and 1950s. But there are many words that were once more popular than they are now, and you might call them "old-fashioned" but not "archaic"—consider 'clever', 'coeds', 'pompadour', 'whoopee' https://goo.gl/uyQrOh

Comment: @nohat - Your first reference above was a game, with contrived terminology.  The second was a story set in the 50s or 60s.  I've not seen a bona fide current usage of the word.

Comment: @HotLicks it's kind of like a "No True Scotsman" approach to word usage... but here you go: "it wasn’t long before a *jalopy* of a bus trundled along and we hopped on" http://goo.gl/uXYjUI "I can drive home in my old *jalopy* just as well as in a Cadillac." http://goo.gl/atQVWE "it would be a waste of time to spruce up your 12-year-old *jalopy* and try to pass it off as new" http://goo.gl/u2EAgs "trade in that beat-up 1970's *jalopy* for something newer" http://goo.gl/nVhegn "Eventually an old *jalopy* shows up with [Neil] Young... at the wheel" http://goo.gl/CVO3mU

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalupa_%28boat%29 seems to be a good candidate for Jalopy origin. J is pronounced as ch or kh depending on the dialect of spanish.

Answer (score 53):

### [Banger](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/banger)

*noun, British informal*

> An old car in poor condition: *they’ve only got an old banger*

More example sentences:

> On a family visit to Windsor Safari Park just to get used to his new car, a *jumpy old banger* with steering wheel stick-shift gears, Ron was flagged down by a policeman.
>
> They are not supposed to be working but their entrepreneurial skills include buying *old bangers* at the car market and fixing them up for resale.

You can amplify your meaning with the adjective **clapped-out**:

### [Clapped-out](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/clapped-out?s=t)

*adjective, British informal*

> (of machinery or appliances) worn-out; dilapidated.

[Example](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clapped-out):

> 'These same emissions zones will also catch *clapped-out old bangers* and poorly-maintained lorries and vans.'

Comment: 'Clapped-out' looks a good adjective to me. Technically, I suppose it's two words, but you may want to consider including?

Comment: I've added some more on Clapped-out, @JulieCarter. Thanks!

Comment: Yvw:) @EleventhDoctor

Comment: @JulieCarter: Doesn't `clapped-out` mean out of order? The OP's car still works.

Comment: Interestingly the OED definition says 'unable to work or operate' yet all the OED examples imply ongoing usage: 'A group of Bradford friends are planning an ambitious 3,222 mile charity crusade around the UK - in a set of four clapped-out old Ford Fiestas.' - http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clapped-out

Comment: "clapped out" means pretty much out of order, but still running anyway despite all logic and reason. For how much longer, is not specified... It's also appropriately onomatopoetic, they sound like they're clapping when you rev them.

Comment: @TusharRaj I checked and Cambridge, McMillan and Longman all define as 'sort of working'. Collins implies that too. :)

Comment: @JulieCarter: I was going by the quoted Oxford definition. I eat my words. +1 for the Doctor.

Comment: Yes, *Morris Marina*, *Vauxhall Chevette*, *Fiat Uno* and *Austin Montego* were among the *bangers* that my dad drove around when I was a kid.  When they were running.  Since moving to the US, I have discovered the related term [4-banger](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=4+Banger) to specifically mean car with a 4-cylinder engine, though I think the connotation is often that it is also a "*beater*".

Comment: I saw a sign once outside a scrapyard which played on the dual meaning of _banger_. It said, “We turn your bangers into mash”. I thought that was rather clever.

Comment: @JulieCarter Have you an authority stating that hyphenated compounds 'are technically two words'?

Comment: Hi @EdwinAshworth no, sorry, I wasn't sure how 'clapped-out' would be regarded, as it is treated as two separate words in CDO. If you know of guidance on hyphenating, that would be great. I am unsure whether there is a difference between standalone words, such as 'clapped' and 'out', and words such as 'e-mail', which would become 'electronic mail'? Thanks!

Comment: @JulieCarter I think that with compounds, terminology is not standardised. To my mind, it's unhelpful to label _particleboard_ as one word but _particle board_ two (and who decides on what to call _particle-board_? They're all acceptable spellings.) There have been articles on ELU about alternative spellings (open, hyphenated and closed compounds) and their evolution/s (compounds becoming solid more quickly in the US than in the UK, in general). Often, attributive compound adjectives are hyphenated whereas their predicative near-twins are not.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you for your helpful response. I'll take a look at the ELU articles you mentioned.

Answer (score 29):

You might consider one of the many slang words for such a car -- [hooptie](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hooptie), [junker](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/junker), [clunker](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clunker), [beater](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/beater), etc.

Sources:  Urban Dictionary and  The Free Dictionary.

Comment: +1 *hooptie* and *beater* are new words for me, so I clicked on the links...

Comment: Clunker is good in American English. Natives might recall the "Cash for Clunkers" program a few years back, where the government offered small financial incentives to turn old, fuel-inefficient cars into the govt, since newer models nearly all have better mileage than their equivalents from decades ago.

Comment: I know we are not voting, but _beater_ was the first term that came to mind for me. We also use the term to apply to bicycles in similar shape as in "Train station beater" which is a cheap or old bike kept locked up at a train station - the implication being that replacing it occasionally is cheaper/easier than finding a more secure place to store a bike (midwest, USA).

Comment: "Beater" is also the only word in any of these answers which I would use. "Hooptie" is a sub-category of beater to me: a hooptie is a luxury car which is at least 20 years old, and in poor enough condition to be a beater.

Answer (score 17):

In Australia, a poorly maintained/rusty car is called a "bomb" or a "bomby car" and described as "bomby".

> 'Look at that bomby Falcon - it's the rustiest thing I've ever seen!'
>
> 'Wow, that red Corolla's an absolute bomb!'

---

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decrepit_car):

> In Australian slang the terms rust bucket, 'bunky', old bomb, paddock basher or bomb are used to refer to old, rusty and/or rundown cars.

---

> **bomb**
>
> *noun*
>
> (*Australia/New Zealand, slang*) an old or dilapidated motorcar

*Source: Collins English Dictionary*

Comment: It's an excellent point that Bomb is AusE ... Banger is BrE and Junker is AmE.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a noun that can fit your description: [rattletrap](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rattletrap)

From Merriam Webster:

> something (such as a car) that is old, noisy, and not in good condition

Comment: Please cite the source of your link/quoted definition somewhere in the body of this answer.

Comment: Well it's a quoted definition from the link on rattletrap

Answer (score 11):

Here in Australia, we use the term "shitbox" (a slang) to refer to cars that are in bad condition, or cars that are just bad.

> Mate, my car's a shitbox. Barely gets to the local pub before she
>   shits herself.

Before you flame me for profanity (if you even consider that word profanity in this day and age), here's a link to an official rally that is run here in Australia. http://www.shitboxrally.com.au/

Comment: awesome mate.  the best answer :)

Comment: Formula 1's Olivier Panis used this word to describe the Morris Marina in an episode of Top Gear. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJ4yP9BIkII

Answer (score 10):

**[Battered](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/battered)** comes to mind.

> old, used a lot, and not in very good condition
>
> *a battered old car*

That's the actual example from Oxford

---

A cursory synonym search didn't yield many words applicaple to cars, except this (sort of):

**[ramshackle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ramshackle)**

> (Especially of a house **or vehicle**) in a state of severe disrepair:
> a ramshackle cottage

I'd go with `battered`, though.

Comment: In AmE we would not use "ramshackle" to describe a car, "battered" is so-so. +1 for an answer with definitions, citations and links. They seem quite rare these days. :-(

Comment: @LittleEva: That's what I thought. Hence the 'sort of'. And re-recommendation of battered. (Which isn't just so-so, but perfect, IMO)

Comment: Yes. But not in the senses you'd expect.

Comment: [See for yourself](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=site:www.thehindu.com+%22battered%22)

Comment: It's difficult to see how "some adjectives" can be an answer to the question "what word is used for a [junker] in such and such country?".

Answer (score 10):

**[Heap](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/heap)**

> an untidy or dilapidated place or vehicle.
>   "they climbed back in the heap and headed home"

Comment: + 1 That's a good one. Can you link to your sources? Is this a particularly British English usage?

Comment: Sadly my original source is usage. That the dictionary also lists it in their example but beyond that, I'm not having much luck finding it using google's ngram viewer... trying to come up with a short phrase that also maintains context is hard.

Comment: @EleventhDoctor It's not idiomatic British English; the link is to Oxford Dictionaries' American site.

Answer (score 9):

**decrepit** (*adj.*):

worn out or ruined, because of age or neglect

> '*a row of decrepit houses*'

*Source:* [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Some information on the **'decrepit car'** is given through [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decrepit_car)

Using two words will give you an **'old banger'** (*noun:British informal*):

an old car in poor condition

> *'they've only got an old banger'*

*Source:* [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/banger)

Answer (score 8):

*[heap](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/heap)*:

> 3 informal An untidy or dilapidated place or vehicle:
>
> *Oxford Dictionaries Online*

or *[beater](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/beater)*:

> 4 North American informal An old or dilapidated vehicle.
>
> *Oxford Dictionaries Online*

My [1940 Ford Fordor](http://cdn.barrett-jackson.com/staging/carlist/items/Fullsize/Cars/81831/81831_Side_Profile_Web.jpg) that is mostly original parts is a *survivor*, but that term is used only by hot rod enthusiasts.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Craig. Please notice the improvements I've made to your answer. We'd like you to maintain that as a minimum standard for any answers you post in the future.

Comment: +1 for the answer I see *post*-edit.

Answer (score 6):

***Flivver*** comes to mind also beside modern slang terms. The use of *jalopy* superseded *flivver* over time but *flivver* has this nostalgic feel.

> A flivver is an American slang term used during the early part of the 20th century to refer to any small car that gave a rough ride, esp. one that is small, inexpensive, and old. A contemporary term was a **"Tin Lizzy"** (referring to a Ford Model T). [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flivver)

[image]
<sub>Chevy, old American car. Habana, Cuba - *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flivver)*</sub>

It is an outdated term itself but it is still used, especially in novels.

> From "The Wild Years" by Ernest Hemingway (1962):
>
> *The luge is the Swiss flivver.*

*Flivver* is also used for cheap and old aeroplanes. The Ford Flivver was a single-seat aircraft introduced by Henry Ford as the "Model T of the Air".

[image]

Comment: Bravo! Wonderful nostalgic / archaic choice.

Answer (score 6):

#### An Embarassment of Choices (For Describing an Embarrasing Car)

There are many terms you might use for a [decrepit car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decrepit_car)<sup>**1**</sup>

> Numerous slang terms are used to describe such cars, which vary by country and region, including *hoopty*, *jalopy*, *shed*, *clunker*, *lemon*, *banger*, *bomb*, *beater*, *rust bucket*, *voodoo*, *wreck*, or *rattletrap*.

#### More Colorful Choices

Another possible term is [*bucket of bolts*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bucket+of+bolts)<sup>**2**</sup>

> a machine which is old run-down, or worn out

another possibility is [*death trap*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Death+Trap)<sup>**2**</sup>

> *Man, we had to ride in this old car to get to the mall. Things were clanking and the breaks were like almost gone on the thing. That car was nothing more than a death trap, and I am surprised we made it there and back in one piece.*

<sup>**1**<sub>From [Wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org/)</sub></sup>

<sup>**2**<sub>From [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/)</sub></sup>

Answer (score 5):

**shed**

It's a niche British English use for a cheap knockabout car.

Pistonheads.com run a weekly Shed of the week article: http://www.pistonheads.com/regulars/ph-features-sheds

Answer (score 3):

- run-down

: in very bad condition because of age or lack of care

http://i.word.com/idictionary/run-down

Answer (score 3):

All of my cars in the '70s were "beaters." Aka "rust-buckets" or "heaps." And a few were quite literally possible "deathtraps." (Like the one that dropped a tie rod in a.m. rush-hour traffic on a 4-lane highway; or the engine fire in the middle of the night, on a rural desert road; to fondly recall a couple.) These were the most common names we used for our "junkers" in the Midwest US at the time. A bit of trivia - Average cost: $100-150. Average lifespan: 6-9 months. Money back at the junkyard: $50.

Answer (score 2):

"beater car" is the term I use for my old beat up backup/don't care where I park/leave it car.

Answer (score 2):

An old *kronk*, a *clapped-out* motor are my favourites. More [over at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decrepit_car).

Comment: Yes, but we used to spell it as old cronk.

Answer (score 2):

I live in the city, and I hear it particularly from older guys, but may I suggest

**Hoopty**

Noun
hoopty *(plural hoopties)*

*(slang) an old, worn-out car.*

(Source: Wiktionary)

Usage: "Your hoopty's missin a hubcap, man!"
If I remember correctly, it's got origins in Detriot, but someone might have to check me on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to describe a car that only looks old and worn out but still runs well, consider *rat rod*: a style of antique car restoration which leaves rust and other effects of time unaltered, or even simulates them.

Answer (score 0):

'dilapidated vehicle' is the best that I can think of. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I like **lemon**:

> something that is useless because it fails to work or to work
>   properly:
>
> *I soon realized the van was a lemon.*

(Longman)

In *Cars 2* they use the word *lemon* many times to describe old rusty cars that malfunction all the time:

> The world turned their backs on cars like us. **They stopped manufacturing us, stopped making our parts.** The only thing they haven't stopped doing is laughing at us. They've called us terrible names: jalopy, rust bucket, heap, clunker, junker, beater, wreck, rattletrap...**lemon**.

(https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Cars_2)

Comment: It's far more common for the tag "lemon" to be applied to a new car than an old one.  (And the *Cars* movies are a poor reference, being oriented to children under about age 12, and often using synthetic dialects.)

Comment: I just like the movie and the word, pray, good sir, don't be a party poop :)

Answer (score 0):

[***down-at-the-heel***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/down-at-heel)

> adj.
>
> 1. Worn out from long use or neglect; dilapidated.
> 2. Shabbily dressed because of poverty; seedy.

Source: American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition.

> [***Down-at-the-heel cars***](https://books.google.fr/books?id=VgYEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=%22down+at+the+heel+cars+does+everything+on+the+car+work%22&source=bl&ots=j-KaHG99Dc&sig=ipPCJi58uxzXaLZKj6Fg5Xn-uoc&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn9oXb8rPWAhXHOBoKHbg1CTEQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22down%20at%20the%20heel%20cars%20does%20everything%20on%20the%20car%20work%22&f=false)

Source: Kiplinger's Personal Finance (1951)

[***roadworn***](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/roadworn)

> : Worn out by long travel on roads, or (figuratively) in a damaged or depleted state due to constant or prolonged usage or exertion.
>
> Mark Anthony, The Dark Remains, Bantam Spectra (2001), ISBN 0553579355, page 10: *Now that they were close, Lirith could see the vehicles were more than a little **roadworn**: wood cracked, gilt peeled, and dust flecked sun-faded paint.*

Source: Wiktionary