# Cheap and tiny car (ironic/derogative)

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to translate to English a German sentence where a car is called a "Schlaglochsuchgerät" (literally: "Pothole detector"), which is an ironic name for cars small enough to fit into a big pothole, with small tires that make for a really bumpy ride on degraded roads.

"What makes you think five people could fit into your __________?"
"If the condition of that road degrades for another year or two, I may have to trade in my ________ for an AWD."

Comment: There isn't really a term for this in the US, where tiny cars are rare.  Perhaps in England ...

Comment: If it's clear from context why not translate it just as you have here?

Comment: My first car was very much a pothole detector. Good description. Such cars may also be called 'lurchers' (usually a breed of dog).

Comment: Toy car perhaps?

Comment: Rattletraps. Originally not about cars. The word predates them. Generally has more to do with cheap build quality, poor maintenance, and age degradation. Doesn't really imply tiny. But it makes a nice parallel to pot hole detector, which I really like, btw.

Comment: Of related interest (not duplicate): *[An old car in bad condition](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255926/an-old-car-in-bad-condition)*.

Answer (score 2):

There are 5 that might work:

***Pillbox*** (which was a term by father always used in reference to the VW Beetle):  *There's no way we can fit the whole team into that pillbox!  We need something bigger.*

***Matchbox***:  *If you really wanna impress your girlfriend, that comical matchbox won't do.*

***Roller skate***:  *Did you see the car Chuck just bought?  It's only got 2 seats.  How's he gonna fit his Great Dane in that roller skate?*

[***Pocket rocket***](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/pocket-rocket) (the emphasis being on the contrast between the fact that the car is small but powerful): *Hey, don't knock my pocket rocket!  Dynamite comes in small packages!*

[***4-banger***](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/4-banger) (this is the opposite of PR, in terms of power):  *He's got 4 kids now, but he's still driving that 4-banger.*

Comment: I think these are all good for size +1, but miss out on the bumpy journey.

Comment: @SConroy  Yah, I know.  It's hard to find a useable term that unites both qualities.

Comment: Roller skate, as in "pregnant roller skate", used to be CB slang for VW beetles/bugs.

Comment: I think Pocket Rocket and Four Banger don't apply to OP's question at all.  What prompted you to include them?

Answer (score 1):

“Tin can” is the term I’ve heard and used myself. Such a car is small and light-weight but not necessarily old.

Answer (score 0):

For a low quality and cheesy car LEMON is a good word and for an old car CLUNKER but neither refer to the size. You might say cramped lemon/clunker
You can find both in reliable dictionaries

Comment: Neither of these focus on size ?

Answer (score 0):

Small and economical cars are called **microcars**. They can fit into a big pothole. Usually, they are one sitter or two sitter cars.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcar

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Roller skate, go-cart, pocket rocket. are common descriptions of cars like that. The cars shown above are called 'bubble cars'.